# How to create a timeline chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to create the following chart:

[image]

This chart displays for every month and person the categories and its values.
The table i have is in the following format:

[image]

I've managed to create a slicer which displays the data correctly but is not like the chart above:

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve a chart just like first image?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to create a matrix visual with Personen and ProjectName in rows, Date as column and Values as values, drilling down so the subsections would be visible too. You would copy this and for each visual filter the month you need. The name of the month would be handled simply by a text field.
The only weak spot, if so, would be it's static. Small multiples can't do this for matrix visuals yet, so you would have to dig for a 3rd party alternative (I haven't found one though)